# Compile VLC from source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc-media-player, compile

I want my `cvlc` client RTSP recording stream to be not closed when the source is disconnected, so it can continue recording after source is available. So I found this topic in VLC forum, which says that the timeout value is hard coded:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=100357

I have downloaded the source files of VLC, and I've changed the value where needed, but I don't know how to compile VLC from source.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can go to wiki page from the official site: https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/ i think this will help.

Answer (score 1):

#### I don't know how to compile VLC from source.

> **Generic Steps**
>
> These are the main steps to follow to compile VLC :
>
> 1. Prepare your compile environment,
> 2. Grab the source of VLC media player,
> 3. Bootstrap, using the ./bootstrap script, if you took the code from repository,
> 4. Prepare the extras libraries needed for VLC media player, read the list,
> 5. Configure,
> 6. Build, using make,
> 7. and Profit!

Source [Category:Building](https://wiki.videolan.org/Category:Building/)

Detailed steps for Linux, BSD or other Unices can be found at [UnixCompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/)